# Having issues with persistence. When its in the code, the acknowledge button does not work, specifically the "userid" value

Tags: python, discord.py

When I have persistence, userid (self.user_id) is no longer able to be converted to an integer, and can't be used within other functions. When I don't have persistence, userid is able to be converted to an integer, and the checks are working.

This is my code:

```
# core.py
import os
import datetime
import discord
import discord.ext

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Embed 
from discord.app_commands import Choice

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

intents = discord.Intents.all() 
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

class PersistentView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user_id: str):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.user_id = user_id

    @discord.ui.button(label="Acknowledge", emoji="<:check:1135773225423491122>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id='persistent_view:acknowledge')
    async def menu1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        new_embed = Embed.from_dict(interaction.message.embeds[0].to_dict())
        new_embed.set_footer(text=f'Sent by {interaction.user.name}     |     Acknowledged: ✔')
        userid = self.user_id
        userid = int(userid)
        if interaction.user.id == userid:
            new_embed = Embed.from_dict(interaction.message.embeds[0].to_dict())
            now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
            time = now.strftime("%I:%M %p")
            new_embed.set_footer(text=f'Acknowledged: ✔  ●  Interacted at {time} UTC')
            
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=new_embed)
            button.disabled = True
            await interaction.message.edit(view=self)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You cannot interact with this button.", ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Revoke", emoji="<:Cross:1135773287880867900>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,  custom_id='persistent_view:revoke')
    async def menu2(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # rest of the code for the revoke button
        user = interaction.guild.get_member(interaction.user.id)
        role1 = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=994233392478560297)
        role2 = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=994233182532685825)
        if role1 in user.roles or role2 in user.roles:
            new_embed = Embed.from_dict(interaction.message.embeds[0].to_dict())
            color_code = "8b0000"
            r, g, b = tuple(int(color_code[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
            color = discord.Color.from_rgb(r, g, b)
            new_embed.color = color
            new_embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1186396627645243392/1187292785548734554/red.png?ex=65965b92&is=6583e692&hm=1807b6934c0ae50dc42ca2831c33157234d9c0c7c19f8030015bccd6805e76ca&")
            channel = bot.get_channel(1187290749977514045)
            await channel.send(f"**Punishment Revoked by {interaction.user.mention}**", embed=new_embed)
            await interaction.message.delete()
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have the required role to use this button.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.tree.command(name="infract")
@app_commands.describe(userid = "User being infracted (ID only)")
@app_commands.describe(reason = "Reason for infraction")
@app_commands.describe(type = "Choose a type")
@app_commands.choices(type=[
    Choice(name='Termination', value=1),
    Choice(name='Demotion', value=2),
    Choice(name='Infraction', value=3),
    Choice(name="Blacklist", value=4),
    Choice(name="Under Investigation", value=5)
])
@app_commands.describe(note = "Any notes that should appear on the command response (put N/A if none)")

async def infract(interaction: discord.Interaction, userid: str, reason: str, type: Choice[int], note: str):
    color_code = "c8ac8e"
    r, g, b = tuple(int(color_code[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
    color = discord.Color.from_rgb(r, g, b)
    embed=discord.Embed(description=f'### <:CRPLASD:1135980746968936571> *___**`{type.name}`**___*\n\n**`User:`** <@{userid}>\n**`Reason:`** {reason}\n**`Action:`**{type.name}\n**`Note:`** {note}\n\n*Sent by {interaction.user.mention}*', color=color)
    embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1186396627645243392/1186406667580088392/asddasasd.png?ex=6593224f&is=6580ad4f&hm=940ce8a8ab6ab9bd5fe32a144bc41282cb5a3020ca96c235d4cdf0181c3f4838&")
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Acknowledged: ✖')
    user_id = userid # get the user id from the command option
    view = PersistentView(user_id) # create a MyView object with the user id
    await interaction.response.send_message("Infraction Sent", ephemeral=True)
    await interaction.channel.send(f'<@{userid}>', embed=embed, view=view) # send the message with the button and the view

class PersistentViewBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
    
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        self.add_view(PersistentView(discord.ui.View))

bot = PersistentViewBot()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I've tried changing around the arguments, but that does not work. I am honestly stuck and clueless here, so anything helps.

*Persistence code can be found at the end of the code block above.*

Comment: `self.add_view(PersistentView(discord.ui.View))` is wrong. You must use `self.add_view(PersistentView(USER_ID_HERE))`